# iccube : how to count number of members with where clause in a mdx?

Tags: mdx, iccube, mdx-query

Using the following mdx, the result is the same if I run it with or without the where clause : It returns the total nbr of years in the hierarchy.

```
with member nbYears as [Time].[Year].[Year].count
select nbYears on 0
from [Sales]
where [Time].[2007]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Existing MDX](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Existing.php) function

```
WITH 
   member nbYears as (Existing [Time].[Year].[Year]).count
SELECT nbYears on 0
FROM [Sales]
WHERE [Time].[2007]
```